# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py.xml (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for py.xml

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I want to modify the columns of the result table of pytest report using the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from py.xml import html
import pytest

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.th('Description'))
    cells.insert(1, html.th('Time', class_='sortable time', col='time'))
    cells.pop()

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.td(report.description))
    cells.insert(1, html.td(datetime.utcnow(), class_='col-time'))
    cells.pop()

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.description = str(item.function.__doc__)
```

To use the above code, I am trying to install py.xml. While using `pip install py.xml`. , I am getting the below error messgae:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py.xml (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for py.xml

Please let me know how to resolve this issue

Comment: `pytest` will install `py` automatically if done correctly. Run `pip install pytest --upgrade` to refresh the installation, missing packages should be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the pylib xml module it is provided by `pip install py` (usually a transitive dependency of pytest so you may already have it installed)

That said, you may want to consider using a different library as `py` is being phased out:

> NOTE: this library is in maintenance mode and should not be used in new code.

(from [the readme](https://github.com/pytest-dev/py))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since **py** is being phased out, which plugin I need to install to use html.th and html.td?

Comment: you'd have to find some other library which has equivalent functionality -- I don't know how `html.X` function but I assume any popular xml library will work fine (or a simple wrapper around stdlib `html` might even suffice)